# issue with inserting to database

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I want to insert the contents of result2 which is description, quantity, price, discount and total as well as some added variables into another table(displaybilling).

I put the insert into displaybilling query within a while loop and somehow it is not working. Sorry im new to php and databases.

Next page's code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){



$totalsum = $_POST["total_amt"];
$custname = $_POST["customer_name"];
$paid = $_POST["paid"];
$today=date('d-m-Y');
$outstanding = $totalsum - $paid;

global $connection;
$query = "INSERT INTO displayoutstanding (";
$query.= " cust_name, date, paid, final_total, oustanding";
$query.= ") VALUES (";
$query.= " '{$custname}', '{$today}', {$paid}, {$totalsum}, {$outstanding}";
$query.= ")";

$finished = mysqli_query($connection, $query);




echo "<table border='1'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Services Rendered</th>\n";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
echo "<th>Price($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Amount</th>\n";
echo "</tr>";

global $connection;

$sql1="SELECT description,quantity, amount, discount, total FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$custname' GROUP BY description ORDER BY id";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['quantity'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['discount']. "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $rows['total']  . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";


            $name = $rows['description'];
            $today=date('d-m-Y');
            $quantity = $rows['quantity'];
            $amount = $rows['amount'];
            $discount = $rows['discount'];


            global $connection;
            $query = "INSERT INTO displaybilling (";
            $query.= " cust_name, date, description, quantity, price, discount, total_amt";
            $query.= ") VALUES (";
            $query.= " '{$cname}', '{$today}', '{$name}', {$quantity}, {$amount}, {$discount}, {$total}";
            $query.= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

          }    
          echo "</table>";

          echo "Total Amount:";
          echo "&nbsp;";
          echo $totalsum;
          echo "<br />";

          echo "Customer Name:";
          echo "&nbsp;";
          echo $custname;
          echo "<br />";

          echo "Date:";
          echo "&nbsp;";
          echo $today;
          echo "<br />";

          echo "Customer Paid:";
          echo "&nbsp;";
          echo $paid;
          echo "<br />";

          echo "Outstanding fee:";
          echo "&nbsp;";
          echo $outstanding;
          echo "<br />";







}

?>
```

Code

```
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Services Rendered</th>\n";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
echo "<th>Price($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Amount</th>\n";
echo "</tr>";

$cname = $_GET["cname"];

global $connection;

$sql1="SELECT description,quantity, amount, discount, total FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname' GROUP BY description ORDER BY id";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['quantity'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['discount']. "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $rows['total']  . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $name = $rows['description'];
            $today=date('d-m-Y');
            $quantity = $rows['quantity'];
            $amount = $rows['amount'];
            $discount = $rows['discount'];


            global $connection;
            $query = "INSERT INTO displaybilling (";
            $query.= " cust_name, date, description, quantity, price, discount, total_amt";
            $query.= ") VALUES (";
            $query.= " '{$cname}', '{$today}', '{$name}', {$quantity}, {$amount}, {$discount}, {$total}";
            $query.= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

          }         
          echo "</table>";
          ?>





          <?php
          $sql1="SELECT SUM(total) as total_amt_2 FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>". "Total Amount:" ."$". $row['total_amt_2']  . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";


          $sumtotal = $row['total_amt_2'];

          echo "<form action=\"invoiceconirm.php\" method=\"POST\">";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"total_amt\" value=\"$sumtotal\" />";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cust_name\" value=\"$cname\" />";
          echo "Customer Paid:";
          echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"paid\" value=\"\"/>";
          echo "<br />";
          echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>";
          echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\" onclick=\"window.location='manage_content.php';\"/>";
          echo "</form>";

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of your form inputs are in quotes... They were just outputting as $sumtotal and $cname, so no information was actually being passed from the php script to the HTML.

This should work.

```
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Services Rendered</th>\n";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
echo "<th>Price($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Amount</th>\n";
echo "</tr>";

$cname = $_GET["cname"];

global $connection;

$sql1="SELECT description,quantity, amount, discount, total FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname' GROUP BY description ORDER BY id";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['quantity'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['discount']. "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $rows['total']  . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $name = $rows['description'];
            $today=date('d-m-Y');
            $quantity = $rows['quantity'];
            $amount = $rows['amount'];
            $discount = $rows['discount'];


            global $connection;
            $query = "INSERT INTO displaybilling (";
            $query.= " cust_name, date, description, quantity, price, discount, total_amt";
            $query.= ") VALUES (";
            $query.= " '{$cname}', '{$today}', '{$name}', {$quantity}, {$amount}, {$discount}, {$total}";
            $query.= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

          }         
          echo "</table>";
          ?>





          <?php
          $sql1="SELECT SUM(total) as total_amt_2 FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>". "Total Amount:" ."$". $row['total_amt_2']  . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";


          $sumtotal = $row['total_amt_2'];

          echo "<form action=\"invoiceconirm.php\" method=\"POST\">";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"total_amt\" value=\"".$sumtotal."\" />";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cust_name\" value=\"".$cname."\" />";
          echo "Customer Paid:";
          echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"paid\" value=\"\"/>";
          echo "<br />";
          echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>";
          echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\" onclick=\"window.location='manage_content.php';\"/>";
          echo "</form>";

          }
```

Comment: actually, the values of the form can be parsed to the next page. It's working but i can't insert into the database. I'll paste the next page's code in the next comment

Comment: It was too long so i editted the question. I put my next page's code under Next Page's code in the question